# Get value from gridview column that has radio button using javascript in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Here is my gridview with radio button

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeader="False" runat="server" cellpadding="5"
              cellspacing="1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="512px">
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbt"  onclick="javascript:Selrdbtn(this.id)"  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

It calls this script, which helps select only one radio button

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

      function Selrdbtn(id) {
          var rdBtn = document.getElementById(id);

          var grid = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

        var List = grid.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
            if (List[i].type == "radio" && List[i].id != rdBtn.id) {
                List[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

How do I get row values where radio button is selected?

Comment: It would help if you could show how Selrdbtn(id) is being called, can you post that ?

Comment: Do you want to get the row values within the JavaScript(cient side) or Code behind(server side) ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by row values? Do you want the contents of the table cells in the row that is checked? Also the Jquery library could be very helpful here, have you used that before or are you open to using it? I see you have tagged the question as jQuery but your code is more straight javascript.

Comment: @sh1rts <asp:RadioButton ID="rbt"  onclick="javascript:Selrdbtn(this.id)"  runat="server" > here it gets called.

Comment: @AliShahrokhi row values from server side.

Comment: @JonP table cell values of the selected radio button row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the row values of the selected check-box you need to do first: *add two more properties in your check-box control like this*:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbt" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rbt_CheckedChanged" 
                 AutoPostBack="true" onclick="javascript:Selrdbtn(this.id);" />
```

`OnCheckedChanged` property would fire an event called `rbt_CheckedChanged` on your code behind and `AutoPostBack` would take the action on your control.

Then you need to *loop through your grid-view* on your code behind util you find the selected value in the grid-view and get the rest of the control's values at the same time.

```
protected void rbt_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((sender as CheckBox).ClientID == (row.FindControl("rbt") as CheckBox).ClientID)
        {
            string checkboxValue = (row.FindControl("rbt") as CheckBox).Checked.ToString();
            string textboxValue = (row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text;

            // you could get all of the selected row's values the same as above code.

            break; //break the loop once it finds the result
        }
    }
}
```

On the code above I've put two sample controls to show you how to get the values of the selected row so you could get any types of control's value yourself.

Cheers